# Send emails to external addresses

Tags: anonymity, security, windows, vpn, email

I would want to send emails to external addresses from an external web site (for example contact@mywebsite.com or .org etc) from my mail2tor account, but I received the next e-mail:

> Subject:   Delayed Mail (still being retried) From:   "Mail Delivery
>   System"  Date:   Wed, March 23, 2016 8:39
>   am To:   myaccount@mail2tor.com Priority:   Normal
>
> This is the mail system at host mail.mail2tor.com.
>
> #
>
> ## THIS IS A WARNING ONLY.  YOU DO NOT NEED TO RESEND YOUR MESSAGE.
>
> #
>
> Your message could not be delivered for more than 4 hour(s). It will
>   be retried until it is 7 day(s) old.
>
> For further assistance, please send mail to postmaster.

I sent an email from administrator requiring more information, but I don't received a response until now. I would know if exist any solution on this? Or as I can to do to send emails in anonymously and security? I thought that I can to use a VPN and use a normal services from send emails: Yahoo, Gmail, Microsoft account, etc, but using a VPN. Do you know a VPN to use with tor browser in windows? I found the IPVanish VPN, but I would have to pay to use it, and I haven't money.
On the other way, I read in other post, that if I received a response, this could to be in the spam folder, but, I cannot to see the spam folder in mail2tor. I only see: Drafts, Sent, Trash, and INBOX. Should I change some configuration to see it?

Thanks and regards, Kathy.

Comment: Seems this may have been just a temporary issue with mail2tor.com? If so, please update your question. Also, there are way too many questions dumped below the first, please try to narrow it down and make more specific.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is a problem with mail2tor.com. I tried to send emails to other servers using mail2tor several times. Although a few of them succeded, most of them failed.

Comment: OK, Thanks. I'll try to send mails again tomorrow (after the 7 days required in the email). On the other hand, do you know a response from my others questions? Regards, Kathy.